# How to hide future or past dates in UIDatePickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to design a UI for setting date of birth. For that I am choosing `UIDatePickerView`. Now I want to restrict the dates to between 01-01-1990 and current date. It should not show future dates and past dates. Currently I am using the following code:

```
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[components setYear:1900];

pickerView.datePicker.minimumDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
pickerView.datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date]
```

It is restricting the dates, but it is allowing the user to scroll to the future dates as well as past dates. How can I hide or avoid them?

I am able to see that feature in the contacts app on the iPad. To see go to Contacts --> press the "+" symbol on top, then press on add birthday button.

Comment: it scroll but visible on gray color, but it not selectable

Comment: That gray color dates has to be hidden .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it scroll but visible on gray color, but it is not selectable, it is not possible to stop on scroll

*To Disable Past date :*

```
 pickerView.datePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];
```

*To Disable Future date :*

```
pickerView.datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date];
```

if you need this compulsory in your app you need to try on some 3rdparty app like [this](https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker)

Comment: is there any mean to achieve this . Like any third party?

Comment: @muralimohan -- I attach the thirdparty also , check the answer

Comment: But i i am able to see that feature in cantacts app in ipad . to see go to cantacts --- >press + symbol on top -- then press on add birthday button -- now see.

Comment: if i run it i am getting blank view.

Comment: @muralimohan -- where you get the blank view , in thirdparty or your native code

Comment: @karthik : in third party.

Comment: @muralimohan -- I am not used that , I search that for you, if want to the same as search in google , you can get related answer, if my answer is fine give the upvote for the answer

Answer (score 2):

To hide future dates, use this code:

```
let now = Date();
pickerviewOutletname.maximumDate = now
```

To hide past dates, use this code:

```
let now = Date();
pickerviewOutletname.minimumDate = now
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer, how does the code answer the question?. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.